# Datetime down to seconds Python

Tags: python, datetime

I have a vector like this:

```
[in]
Dates

[out]
0       2016-04-27 19:56:50
1       2016-04-27 19:56:52
2       2016-04-27 19:56:54
3       2016-04-27 19:56:56
....
9982    2016-04-28 01:29:35
```

I want to read it as a date time object. I am using:

```
import datetime as dt

x = [dt.datetime.strptime(d,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').date() for d in dates]
```

But I dont get all of the information. I only get; year,month,day.

```
[in]
x

[out]
[datetime.date(2016, 4, 27),
 datetime.date(2016, 4, 27),
 datetime.date(2016, 4, 27),
 datetime.date(2016, 4, 27),
 datetime.date(2016, 4, 27), ...]
```

What shall I do to get hours, mins and seconds into "x" as well?

Comment: You shouldn't call `date()` when you want a datetime instead of a date.

Comment: Don't call `.date()` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `datetime.date` object is only that detailed. You want a `datetime.datetime` object instead — just omit the call to `.date()`:

```
import datetime as dt

x = [dt.datetime.strptime(d,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for d in dates]
```

Result:

```
[in]
x

[out]
[datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 27, 19, 56, 50),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 27, 19, 56, 52),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 27, 19, 56, 54),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 27, 19, 56, 56),
 datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 27, 19, 56, 58), ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]
```